# Ignoring exception in command None: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "party" is not found

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
#Command party 

@client.event
async def party(ctx, mikro: str, age: int, game: str, other_inf: str ):
    if ctx.channel.id == 743896262889177131:
        if age <= 0:
            await ctx.send('Ты что не рождался?')
            return
        if age > 120:
            await ctx.send('А не слишком ли ты старый?')
            return
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
        channel = get(ctx.guild.channels, id = 743896304492740691)
        emb = discord.Embed(title = f'{ctx.author.mention} ищет пати', color = 0x25dc84)
        emb.add_field(name = 'Микро', value = mikro, inline = True) 
        emb.add_field(name = 'Возвраст', value = age, inline = True)
        emb.add_field(name = 'Игра', value = game, inline = True)
        embed.add_field(name='Примечания', value=other_inf, inline = True)
        emb.set_author(name=str(ctx.author.name), icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=f'Если хотите откликнуться - нажмите на \nЕсли хотите удалить поиск нажмите ❌')
        await channel.send(embed = embed)
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send('Тут нельзя прописывать эту команду')
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.channel_id != 743896304492740691:
        return
    if payload.member.bot == True:
        return
    channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    embed = message.embeds[0]
    user_embed = embed.author.name
    memb = get(payload.member.guild.members, name=user_embed)
    user = client.get_user(memb.id)
    if payload.emoji.name == '':
        await user.send(content=f'{payload.member} этот человек хочет с вами сыграть')
    if payload.emoji.name == '❌':
        if payload.member.name == user_embed:
            await message.delete(delay=None)
```

.party есть 15 borderlands ага

Answer (score 1):

При создании команды используется `@client.command()`